# javascript- can't pass values between two class instances

Tags: javascript

I have defined one root object that I want to use as "namespace" for the rest of my classes. Inside this root object i have two classes - TOOLS and PRESENTATION. In PRESENTATION class i need to call one of public methods from TOOLS. As I can tell after playing with `console.log` in every step of execution of this code problem is that `return xhr.responseText` don't pass anything back to `tools.getData(configPath)` and I'm ending up with `undefined` in `console.log(pres.config)`.

**CODE:**

```
// Create Namespace
var AppSpace = AppSpace || {}; 

// Class and Constructor
AppSpace.Tools = function() {

        //public methodts
        this.test = function(arg) {
            return arg                      
        }

        this.getData = function(path) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', path, false);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState !== 4) return;
                if (xhr.status !== 0 && xhr.status !== 200) {
                    if (xhr.status === 400) {
                        console.log("Could not locate " + path);
                    } else {
                        console.error("app.getData " + path + " HTTP error: " + xhr.status);
                    }
                    return;
                }
                return xhr.responseText;
              };
              xhr.send();
        } 

}


// Class and Constructor
AppSpace.Presentation = function(initName, initfPath){

        //private properties
        var configPath = initfPath || 'config.json';
        var configData = null;
        var name = initName || 'Unnamed Presentation';  

        //private methods
        var getConfigContent = function() {
            return tools.getData(configPath);
        }

        var getConfigData = function() {
            return JSON.parse(getConfigContent);
        }


        //public methodts


        //public properties
        this.name = null;
        this.config = null;
        this.debug = null;

        //logic
        this.name = name;
        this.config = getConfigContent();


}

//execution
var tools = new AppSpace.Tools();               
var pres = new AppSpace.Presentation('Some Name');

pres.debug = tools.test('value passed')
console.log(pres.debug);
console.log(pres.config);
console.log(pres.name);
```

Output in browsers console is:

```
value passed js-oop.dev:99
**undefined js-oop.dev:100**
Some Name js-oop.dev:101
```

Can anyone give little advice on this? TIA.

Comment: Your XMLHttpRequest is an asynchronous call. Then your function  cannot return its value

Comment: hey man what TIA means? Thanks In Advance?

Comment: Yes, TIA means 'Thanks In Advance' :)

Comment: @Gilles Hemmerlé but when i put `console.log(xhr.responseText)` before `return xhr.responseText` it shows `config.json` content. Can you advice me how to solve this?

Comment: Please check

    JSON.parse(getConfigContent);

I think there should be a call: 'getConfigContent()' instead

Comment: @Gilles Hemmerlé third parameter of XMLHTTPRequest is set to false so it is synchronous.

Comment: Anyway, using only the XMLHttpRequest is not a good practive because not compatible with all browsers, you should use an ajax library or at least create an object that use the correct class available for the user's browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean that if you want that your ajax control return some datas directly from your function you have to use a synchronous method. Without it, datas will be sent from the onreadystatechange  event.

Here is a sample how to create a synchronous call for ajax

```
// Create Namespace
        var AppSpace = AppSpace || {}; 

        // Class and Constructor
        AppSpace.Tools = function() {

                //public methodts
                this.test = function(arg) {
                    return arg                      
                }

                this.getData = function(path) {
                    var xhr_object= new XMLHttpRequest();
                    // Start synchronous ajax
                    xhr_object.open("GET", path, false);
                    xhr_object.send(null);
                    // Return data
                    return xhr_object.responseText;
                } 

        }


        // Class and Constructor
        AppSpace.Presentation = function(initName, initfPath){

                //private properties
                var configPath = initfPath || 'config.json';
                var configData = null;
                var name = initName || 'Unnamed Presentation';  

                //private methods
                var getConfigContent = function() {
                    return tools.getData(configPath);
                }

                var getConfigData = function() {
                    return JSON.parse(getConfigContent);
                }


                //public methodts


                //public properties
                this.name = null;
                this.config = null;
                this.debug = null;

                //logic
                this.name = name;
                this.config = getConfigContent();


        }

        //execution
        var tools = new AppSpace.Tools();               
        var pres = new AppSpace.Presentation('Some Name');

        pres.debug = tools.test('value passed')
        console.log(pres.debug);
        console.log(pres.config);
        console.log(pres.name);​
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in this code:

```
this.getData = function(path) {
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open('GET', path, false);
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xhr.readyState !== 4) return;
                        if (xhr.status !== 0 && xhr.status !== 200) {
                            if (xhr.status === 400) {
                                console.log("Could not locate " + path);
                            } else {
                                console.error("app.getData " + path + " HTTP error: " + xhr.status);
                            }
                            return;
                        }
                        return xhr.responseText;
                      };
                      xhr.send();
                }
```

`return xhr.responseText;` will not work. It is inside handler function and value will be returned from `xhr.onreadystatechange`, but not from `getData`, so you may do something like this:

```
this.getData = function(path) {
                        var res;
                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.open('GET', path, false);
                        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                            if (xhr.readyState !== 4) return;
                            if (xhr.status !== 0 && xhr.status !== 200) {
                                if (xhr.status === 400) {
                                    console.log("Could not locate " + path);
                                } else {
                                    console.error("app.getData " + path + " HTTP error: " + xhr.status);
                                }
                                return;
                            }
                            res = xhr.responseText;
                          };
                          xhr.send();
                          return res;
                    }
```

Also, this should be like next (you are trying to parse an function, not what it returns)

```
 var getConfigData = function() {
     return JSON.parse(getConfigContent());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to keep it asynchrous you can do something like this.  I'd either remove the dest and prop parameters, or the callback, depending on your needs.

```
    this.getData = function(path, dest, prop, callback) {
        callback = callback || null;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', path, false);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState !== 4) return;
            if (xhr.status !== 0 && xhr.status !== 200) {
                /* ... */
            }
            dest[prop] = xhr.responseText;
            if (Callback) callback(xhr.responseText);
          };
          xhr.send();
    } 

    //private methods
    var getConfigContent = function() {
        return tools.getData(configPath, this, 'config', );
    }
```